# Flask: Cannot find JSON file from JS

Tags: javascript, flask

I managed to render an svg animation and export its data as a JSON file (along with a JS file).

I included a JS file that renders the animation and it goes like this:

```js
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('anim'),
    rederer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    path: "data.json"
})
```

However when I serve the file, I get a 404 on the "data.json" file.

- I tried serving the files without flask and it works.
- "data.json" is in the current directory (a static folder) AND in the main directory (where my application is).

My terminal:

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2022 22:52:27] "GET /static/js/lottie.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2022 22:52:27] "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2022 22:52:28] "GET /data.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Is the path `/data.json` correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's `/static/data.json` unless you configured it differently.